# nodejs project transfert mac to mac get error on second mac when sending to heroku import express from 'express'

Tags: node.js, heroku, ecmascript-6, gulp, heroku-cli

I have a problem when transfering my nodeJs api from my personal mac to my work mac.
The error occur when I send the app to heroku server it is send succesfully but I get an error which is :

```
import express from 'express';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I regularly make some local update and then send them to heroku server
I do not get any error from my previous mac

the starting process is not the same 
on my previous mac it was:`npm start`

and the new one is `node server/index.js`

I tried several things:

change procfile value from:`web: node server/index.js` to `web: node server/app.js` and `web: npm start`

I have put `"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"` in my package.json

Before every export to heroku I do: `heroku repo:purge_cache -a my-app`

I also git commit using `--allow-empty`
to export my project I've used :

```
git push heroku master
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```

and then : `npm install`

the version of npm is the same in both computer
    node v8.11.1
    npm 5.6.0

heroku version for both too : `heroku/7.19.4 darwin-x64 node-v11.3.0`

none of this change has been successfull

note that I am looking for a solution to resolve it and do not want to use the old syntax like `const express = require("express")`

Comment: Maybe try updating node to v10.15 lts on your machine that causes this problem

Comment: actually I wanted to stay with lts version, why do you think this is in my machine ?

Comment: One of my friend also had this issue. It was fixed after he upgraded to v10, besides v10.15 is the latest lts version for node right now

Comment: I've installed node v10.15.0 then delete node_module -> npm install then send but same thing

Comment: Please follow this link:- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/%40kimtnguyen/how-to-deploy-es6-node-js-express-back-end-to-heroku-7e6743e8d2ff&ved=2ahUKEwiXx_LNw9vfAhVHiHAKHfBACpYQFjACegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3Ci9rgJ6zhgbT_kCTzxnXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) it is very easy tool see the doc for more info